# Pintar tabla con datos guardados en la base de datos

Tags: php, html, array, while, foreach

Cuando pinta la tabla y la llena muestra los datos de la ultima linea que se guardo, pero en la base de datos si están guardados los valores correctos de los valores anteriores pero en la carga solo muestra la ultima.

```js
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from document where project_id in (".$project_id.
  ")");

if ($project_id <= 1) {

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $array = $row['project_id'];
    $array1 = explode(',', $array);

    $code = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM project WHERE id = $array1");

    if ($code = '') {
      $project = '';
      foreach($code["name"] as $row) {
        $project. = $row.
        ', ';
      }
      $project = substr($project, 0, -2);
    }
  }
} else {

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $array = $row['project_id'];
    $array1 = explode(',', $array);
    $project = '';

    foreach($array1 as $id) {
      $code = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM project WHERE id = $id");

      while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($code)) {
        $project. = $row1['name'].
        ', ';
      }
    }
    $project = substr($project, 0, -2);
  }
}
```

Se guarda el primer registro muestra bien el campo departamento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se guarda el segundo registro muestra bien el campo departamento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se guarda el tercero es cuando da el error en la carga del departamento y cambia el primero y lo deja igual al tercero que se guardo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en la Base de datos si estan bien guardados los valores del departamento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: project id con un monton de numeros separados por coma suena a un mal diseño de la tabla, podrias explicar que estas tratando de hacer con eso?

Comment: Se puede asignar mas de un departamento a un mismo caso, ya que  se crean grupos interdisciplinarios por lo que decidí guardarlo en el mismo campo en la BD y no duplicar el mismo registro con diferente departamento para esto

Comment: Ok. Eso no esta nada bien. Quiere decir que tenes una relacion 1 a N entre la tabla esa y la de proyectos, y por lo tanto deberias tener una tabla intermedia, y te va a solucionar todos estos problemas que estas teniendo.